# how to implement text marking in dom and show popup like grammar checker apps?

Tags: dom, google-chrome-extension, highlight, autosuggest, suggestbox

Want to create a browser extension which will underline specific texts in browser dom. And on click, that text will show a popup with suggestion.
like this:

[image: sample image of a app]